# Array values reutilization in another array definition

Tags: arrays, bash, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to perform an array definition in bash using values of another array as the name of the new array and assign the values inside the array from another array which is dynamically populated.

Here is an example of the code so far:

```
adduser() {
  declare -i segment=$1
  segment_length=${#segment[@]}
  for (( a = 0; a < "${segment_length}"; a++ )); do
    data=($(cat $filename | grep -w ${segment[a]} | awk -F ";" '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/^/ /g'))
    ${segment[a]}=($(echo "${data[*]}"))
  done
}

cat $filename | tail -n+2 | awk -F ";" '{print $2}' | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i }' | sed 's/\r//g' | sort -u > segments.txt
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  'segments=($(cat segments.txt))'
for (( i = 0; i < ${#segments[@]}; i++ )); do
adduser ${segments[i]}
done
```

The objective is to dynamically populate arrays (data in one column of csv) with values from another column and then massively work on them.

The csv has the following format:

```
Header1;Header2
Value1;1 2 3
Value2;2 4 5
```

Take for example the value 2 from column Header2. 
The objective is to dynamically create the array 2 with values Value1 and Value2:

```
2=( Value1 Value2 )
```

**Testing the two answers provided:**

I will continue here as comments are too short: Here is the result from the answer with a random file (same format as the example):

```
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/TestStackoverflow$ awk -F'[; ]' '/;[0-9] / { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s ", $1 > $i".txt" }' real.csv 
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/TestStackoverflow$ ll
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  2 ivo ivo  4096 Nov 27 17:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 28 ivo ivo 32768 Nov 27 17:15 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    99 Nov 27 17:16 155.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo   132 Nov 27 17:16 155?.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    99 Nov 27 17:16 2.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    66 Nov 27 17:16 2?.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo   198 Nov 27 17:16 3.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    33 Nov 27 17:16 3?.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ivo ivo  1369 Nov 27 17:14 real.csv
```

While with the answer above you get the following:

```
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/TestStackoverflow$ ./processing.sh real.csv

ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/TestStackoverflow$ ll
total 112
drwxr-xr-x  2 ivo ivo  4096 Nov 27 17:25 ./
drwxr-xr-x 28 ivo ivo 32768 Nov 27 17:15 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo   100 Nov 27 17:25 102.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo   100 Nov 27 17:25 105.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    67 Nov 27 17:25 106.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    34 Nov 27 17:25 112.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo   991 Nov 27 17:25 155.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo   694 Nov 27 17:25 2.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo   859 Nov 27 17:25 3.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    67 Nov 27 17:25 51.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    67 Nov 27 17:25 58.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    34 Nov 27 17:25 59.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    34 Nov 27 17:25 65.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    34 Nov 27 17:25 67.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    34 Nov 27 17:25 72.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    34 Nov 27 17:25 78.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    34 Nov 27 17:25 81.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivo ivo    34 Nov 27 17:25 82.txt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ivo ivo  1180 Nov 27 17:25 processing.sh*
-rw-r--r--  1 ivo ivo  1369 Nov 27 17:14 real.csv
ivo@spain-nuc-03:~/Downloads/TestStackoverflow$
```

Thanks to everyone for their participation!

Comment: Time to switch to a real programming language.

Comment: Very funny! Please try to be helpful...

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you boil down your problem. And I don't get what `Header2` from the second column has to do with the values from the first column. Also, `2` is not a valid name for a variable.

Comment: I'm not trying to be funny. Every time my shell script is longer than 10 lines or needs real variables and data structures, I rewrite it in Perl.

Comment: @Socowi it does not on the example file... It merely is a header, nothing more...
2 is an example...

Comment: @choroba Well, I have scripts of over 1000 lines long in bash and API Rest integrations...

Comment: I have written >1k line scripts for production automations. I love Perl, but unless you are doing something like trying to build and parse huge, complex memory structures, or a lot of bit-fiddly math, or need massive I/O processing done, I prefer bash. "You might be able to write faster code in C, but you can write code faster in Perl." Sometimes bash is faster than perl... and sometimes not. It's not a matter of how many lines it is.

Comment: As an aside... `data=($(cat $filename | grep -w ${segment[a]} | awk -F ";" '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/^/ /g'))` : OW! OW! OW! Please just use `awk` or `sed` and don't spawn 5 separate processes for this, lol

Comment: I think your best bet here would be to simplify your paradigm. I wouldn't advise this much complexity in Perl, which is much more suited to such shenanigans. Please don't do it in bash. Abstraction is powerful, but it can also make your code totally unusable if applied in excess.

Comment: @PaulHodges you are right in that sed is a bit redundant on the following line:
data=($(cat $filename | grep -w ${segment[a]} | awk -F ";" '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/^/ /g'))
 I make a clear separation between when to use awk and when sed: For dealing with columns in files - Awk; For replacing caracters - Sed... 
Just use the power of the linux shell: Pipe the output from one command into the input of another.
On the matter of abstraction: How would you automate without a layer of abstraction?

Comment: Can you explain the point of the data in the CSV a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All-bash using array -

```
declare -a set=()                          # set is an array
while IFS=';' read -r key lst              # read each line into these 2 splitting on semicolons
do [[ $key =~ Header* ]] && continue       # ignore the header
   read -a val <<< "$lst"                  # split the list of values to the right of the semicolon into an array
   for e in "${val[@]}"                    # for each of those
   do  case "${set[e]:-}" in               
       *$key*) : already here, no-op   ;;  # ignore if already present
           '') set[e]="$key"           ;;  # set initial if empty
            *) set[e]="${set[e]} $key" ;;  # add delimited if new
       esac
   done
done < csv                                 # reads directly from the CSV file
```

At this point the sets should be loaded as space-delimited strings into each element of `set[]`, indexed by the values on the line in the second column of the csv. To print them out for verification -

```
for n in "${!set[@]}"
do echo "$n: ${set[n]}"
done
```

Executed on the test csv content provided:

```
1: Value1
2: Value1 Value2
3: Value1
4: Value2
5: Value2
```

so `set[4]` is `Value2`, and `set[2]` is `Value1 Value2`. You can pull them from there to do whatever is needed.

No need for cat/tail/awk/grep/tr/sed/sort chains.

Does it need something more?

Comment: Good stuff. This was what I was looking for... Now Just inject into Database... Thank you for your time!

Comment: It seems there is a syntaxis problem when I execute it:
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
1: Value1
2: Value1

Comment: Can you check if it is not missing something from the one executed?
Script is exactly the same.
I am executing on Ubuntu 16.04 bash version 4.3.48

Comment: Add this to your script please: `trap ' echo "ERROR $? at $0:$LINENO - [$BASH_COMMAND]" ' err` - it looks like you are trying to execute my output. (You likely don't need the printout at the bottom. I only put that in for you to see the alignment.)

Comment: You might also want to adjust the variable names. I'll add some commentary to make it easier.

Comment: I added it but it doesn't return any additional information. Error stays the same.

Comment: There was a \r caracter somewhere in the file that I removed with sed. Works perfectly now...
Don't worry about variables.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I went for a simpler method according to the comments I got to simplify:

```
cat $1 | tail -n+2 | awk -F ";" '{print $2}' | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i }' | sed 's/\r//g' | sort -u > segments.txt
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  'segments=($(cat segments.txt))'
for (( i = 0; i < ${#segments[@]}; i++ )); do
cat $1 | grep -w ${segments[i]} | awk -F ";" '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/^/ /g' > ${segments[i]}.txt
done
rm segments.txt
```

And then just process the remaining txt files in the folder.

I would really like to see this done in the way I was going initially though as it is more suitable for more data...

Comment: This apparently generates a single column of unique values from the second field of the file, which is your example is the digits from 1 to 5 - then whole-word `grep`s those digits *back* from the CSV to put the first column value into files named <digit>.txt for each digit on the line. Am I reading this right?

Comment: This logic will overwrite "Value1" in 2.txt with "Value2" instead of listing both. Is that the result you wanted? Or would you prefer both be in the file? Did you mean for them to be space-delimited on one line? And did you mean for the lines to have newline endings, or explicitly *not*?

Comment: @PaulHodges The values from column1 should be ordered into sets. Each set has the name of the numerical value from column2. Only the values from column1 are important to appear in the final result... You get sets in the end... Imagine each set as the independent file generated...

Comment: Both sets have 2's in them, and you are writing a file for each number in the set, so there is a 2 in Value1 and Value2, but you are doing a truncating write. I made it an appending write. You were converting newlines to spaces, so I made both values write out with space-delimiting on the same line of the file. Please see my solution. If you prefer newlines, it's easy to make the values one per line. If this isn't what you meant, then you need to explain more clearly, with examples of what the output should be.

Comment: @PaulHodges I did look at it... Please look at the answer I posted as comments are too short.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it right, and assuming you are ok with having no proper newline on the files since you were explicitly squashing them out, this should do all the above in one `awk` call.

```
awk -F'[; ]' '/;[0-9] / { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s ", $1 > $i".txt" }' yourInputFile
```

Comment: Yeah, I stick with the array formatting from previously... Can also go with the new line, depends on what to do next with the sets.
The solution works for the example but not with a random input file respecting the same format as the example.

Comment: Then you need to provide specs and examples that demonstrate the problem. We can only work with what's given.

Comment: My purpose is just to get to the sets construct... Ideally, it should be done with arrays rather than with text files and keep the layer of abstraction, but I guess I need to use something else than bash for that...

Comment: Abstraction is fine - is very good, in fact - but if you call `awk` twice in a pipeline, can you specify why you didn't just handle both tasks in one call? It's like the [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Don't add more processes and complicate the line for maintainers. Please take some time to define your needs and *explain* them. We're here to help, but we need data.

Comment: Could have used sed or cut in place of one of the awk's... Maybe I should remove everything (rest of the script included) and just write an awk script because it can be done with awk one-liner (really long line) according to you? 
If someone would maintain it other than me would get lost. Extra clarity is important. 
Most people don't know how to code in awk, me included. I expect this to be maintained by people who don't know bash well, not to mention awk...

Comment: I'm not exactly an old hand at awk either. :) Give me a little time and I'll try to do an all-bash solution. I just need a **clear**  idea of what you are trying to accomplish.